# How to PUSH a vibration event on Jawbone UP3?

Tags: jawbone

I am willing to be able to make my UP3 vibrate at will.
I cannot find in the API documentation how to achieve it.

A workaround that comes to my mind is eventually adding a task schedule from the apps for the minute after, well, a nicer solution might exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [Developer APIs for UP](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/) do not expose a way to trigger band vibration.

There are several reasons to keep this feature private. Here are a few examples:

1. Band vibration can reduce battery life if triggered too frequently.
2. App-triggered band vibration would require a data sync from the phone to the band, and the band is not always guaranteed to have a bluetooth connection (e.g., the phone could be out of range).
3. Developer application events are not necessarily occurring in real time, so a band vibration in response to an event could occur much later than the event and create a disjointed user experience.

(For more details, on the limitations of real-time behavior, see my response to [UP3 (jawbone) how to retrieve sleep value in REALTIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799916/up3-jawbone-how-to-retrieve-sleep-value-in-realtime)