# How to perform waking up, after 80 seconds of light sleep began

Tags: jawbone

I want to use UP3 for a very specific task, which I should be able to implement using API. I am trying to understand, is it possiblу to write a following application.

Basing on https://jawbone.com/support/articles/000005231/tracking-sleep , the UP3 can catch switching between sleep phases. I need, for example, catch a Light Sleep beginning, wait for 80 seconds and then vibrate for waking up. Can it be done?

After reading documentation I do not understand fundamental applications architecture. I assume, that there should be opened bluetooth channel, and, for example, every 10 seconds I write to the channel sleep status request with 1-2 seconds feedback. Then I write "awake" command which tells the band to vibrate.

Another scenario - somehow I get notification about sleep phase swithcing. Then I start timer, and send this wake-up command.

But these are just my theories. Please explain me, can it be done and how?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is no, this cannot be done.

Here's why:

1. Changes in sleep phase are calculated server-side after the entire sleep event has occurred, so there is no way to receive a real-time notification for a sleep phase change. Here's [another SO question with additional details about this and on how to receive sleep event notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799916/up3-jawbone-how-to-retrieve-sleep-value-in-realtime).
2. Jawbone does not allow third party applications to trigger band vibration. Here's [another SO question with details on why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800885/how-to-push-a-vibration-event-on-jawbone-up3/37816735#37816735).
3. Jawbone does not allow third party applications to connect directly to the band over bluetooth.